# Can the ASA 5505 use pptp as the VPN type? If so does anyone have a link to a config example?

Tags: vpn, cisco-asa, pptp, cisco-pix

I'm migrating from a PIX to a ASA and the PIX has the remote users PPTP to it. This is not pass though but the VPN type of the PIX. Does the ASA even support this? I have been trying to search around but all I have found is for allowing PPTP pass though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PPTP is not a supported feature of ASA 5505 to my knowledge. As you mentioned, VPN pass through is available and instructions are [widely available online.](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1546479)

Comment: Yeah I know I can do that. The issue is that the PIX is currently the PPTP server and with this migration I was hoping to just keep that role on the ASA till I moved the users to AnyConnect, oh well.